# Invalid column reference for Rank function in SQL when using SUM

Tags: sql, mysqli, hive

```
SELECT
*
FROM(
    SELECT 
        imps.org_name, 
        imps.org_id,
        imps.adv_name,
        imps.adv_id,
        imps.mc,
        Rank() over (partition by imps.org_id ORDER by imps.mc desc) as Rank
    FROM(
        SELECT 
            org_name,
            org_id,
            adv_name,
            adv_id,
            sum(cost/1000) as mc, 
        FROM
            table1
        WHERE
            org_id in (12345, 54321)
        AND 
            date 
        BETWEEN 
            '2016-09-10'
        AND 
            '2016-11-01'
        GROUP BY
            adv_id, 
            org_name, 
            org_id, 
            adv_name) imps
    GROUP BY
        imps.org_name, 
        imps.org_id,
        imps.adv_name,
        imps.adv_id) r 
WHERE r.Rank <= 5;
```

When running this query I get the error

```
FAILED: SemanticException Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into   Groups. At least 1 group must only depend on input columns. Also check for circular dependencies.
Underlying error: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Line 10:65 Invalid column reference 'mc'
```

Since that column is clearly defined not sure why it throws the error. 
I've tried sum(imps.mc) and that seems to work but I am uncomfortable putting the sum inside the rank function since it doesn't seem efficient.

Overall question: is there a better way of doing this ranking?

Comment: humor me and make `imps` a Common table expression.  It seems like it should work but perhaps mc hasn't been fully resolved before the window function attempts to execute.  and why the outer group by in `R`; I see no aggregration.

Comment: @xQbert to make imps a common table expression do I just need to add ;imps at the top? Using outer group R since putting Rank<=5 inside results in more errors

Comment: Ah Ha!. remove the comma after mc.   on inner most select (imps)... that's likely the problem.

Comment: ah, comma was just an accident when I was typing it up in here. Even without it still get error. Common table expression works though! Thank you.

Comment: I would take a look at Matt's answer it looks cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I want to try:

- make imps a CTE (common table expression: `with` syntax)  Is the rank getting executed before IMPS generation completes and by making it a CTE will we eliminate that possibility?
- Remove group by on R table: window functions, to my knowledge don't need a group by, and since no other aggregation is occurring why do we need it and could that alone be causing an issue?.
- removed comma after mc on innermost query (Indications were this wasn't in the code just a typo on asking the question)

I'm a big fan of root cause so I'd add by the addition group by and see if it still works if not, we likely have culprit but no idea why.

If we add the group by and it still works, then we likely have a order of execution problem resolved by forcing the engine to generate imps before executing a window function on it.

.

```
With imps as (
        SELECT 
            org_name,
            org_id,
            adv_name,
            adv_id,
            sum(cost/1000) as mc 
        FROM
            table1
        WHERE
            org_id in (12345, 54321)
        AND 
            date 
        BETWEEN 
            '2016-09-10'
        AND 
            '2016-11-01'
        GROUP BY
            adv_id, 
            org_name, 
            org_id, 
            adv_name)
SELECT
*
FROM(
    SELECT 
        imps.org_name, 
        imps.org_id,
        imps.adv_name,
        imps.adv_id,
        imps.mc,
        Rank() over (partition by imps.org_id ORDER by imps.mc desc) as Rank
    FROM IMPS) r 
WHERE r.Rank <= 5;
```

Comment: I'd wonder if it was removing the 2nd group by, or making the CTE that solved this (but that's just me wanting to get to Root cause)

Comment: @Matt earlier comment by LinaP indicates it was not in original source, mistake on her part of posting.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
       SELECT 
          org_name, 
          org_id,
          adv_name,
          adv_id,
          sum(cost/1000) as mc,
          Rank() over (partition by org_id ORDER by sum(cost/1000) desc) as Rank
       FROM
          table1
       WHERE
          org_id in (12345, 54321)
          AND date BETWEEN '2016-09-10' AND '2016-11-01'
       GROUP BY
          adv_id, 
          org_name, 
          org_id, 
          adv_name) r 
WHERE r.Rank <= 5;
```

as xQbert said the "," after MC on the inner most select is likely your main issue with what you presented.  But you also can do the RANK() in the inner most select and eliminate another nested query.  Further, you are not actually aggregating anything in that second query so you can eliminate that second set of group by criteria.

Comment: I have a new book title... "Two Group by's for one select!" :P (looks better now!)

Comment: @xQbert lol that is what I was actually removing and deleting just didn't finish I guess took care of it now.